# Can't load external css when in localhost

Tags: html, css, get, arduino, localhost

I'm working on a project using arduino, node.js and socket.io. I am running it in localhost, however my external stylesheet wont load.

The error seems to be saying it cant get my css from this path http://localhost:1337/css/main.css

However if i keep the css in a style tag in the html file it all works fine, is there a way to keep the css external so it doesnt clutter my html file?

Heres how im loading in my css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
```

Here is how my file structure looks

[image: Folder Structure]

Here is my main.css file inside the css folder

[image: Contents of css folder]

my main.css file is within the css folder, i am working off of the interface.html file

Comment: Could you share what code you are using to load the external stylesheet?

Comment: Sure thing, just updated the question with it

Comment: you need to give the exact location of your file... example like `www.sample.com/css/main.css`

Comment: Does your file structure have the `css` folder beside the html file?

Comment: @SamTengWong do you mean like this? C:\Users\owner\Desktop\comp_web_lesson\example3\css\main.css? this is the path in my command prompt to get to the file

Comment: @KyleBing but your main.css is outside the css folder... doesn't make sense.. or is there another main.css inside css folder?.. in your case you only need to access it directly `href="main.css"`

Comment: ^ What Sam said... or move the main.css inside the css folder.

Comment: @SamTengWong sorry for the confusion, the main.css is both in the css folder and outside of this, i put them in both locations for testing reasons. neither path seems to work regardless of weather the main.css is in the css folder or not

Comment: @KyleBing did you try using `./main.css`?

Comment: @SamTengWong yes I did, had no success with it

Comment: @KyleBing are you sure it is included in your file?

Comment: @SamTengWong yes sir the link tag for the css is in there

Comment: @KyleBing have you tried using this `C:\Users\owner\Desktop\comp_web_lesson\example3\css\main.css`? what is the name of the file that you want to put the external css with?

Comment: @SamTengWong I have tried that long path as well. I am trying to link the external css file with the interface.html file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108457/discussion-between-sam-teng-wong-and-kyle-bing).

Answer (score 5):

Try this instead:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/main.css">
```

notice the `./` in front of the href

otherwise include full path name:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:1337/css/main.css">
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply, however i tried both your answers and they didnt seem to work for me

Answer (score 2):

this is what i have tried and it is working for me

```
 <link href="./main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

To serve static files such as images, CSS files, and JavaScript files, use the express.static built-in middleware function in Express.

The function signature is:
  app.use(express.static(__dirname));

Then you can include like bellow

```
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
</html>
```

Comment: This should be the top answer.

Answer (score 0):

The relative path kicks off from your html path so

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
```

should work (as your main.css is outside of the css folder). Alternatively, you could put the main.css file on the css folder and reference it with "css/main.css"

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same problem as you are facing but i tired below code and it works.

```css
body{
background-color: yellow;
}
h1{
color: red;
}
p{
color:green;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <link href="./external.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>This is my First page to test CSS</h1>
<p>The main motive to making this html file is to test my CSS skill.....</p> 
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks,
hope it will help you......

Answer (score 0):

I'm also facing this problem... But I found a solution and its working. Try the below code line:-

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css?v=<?php echo time(); ?>" />
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you put 4 spaces in front of your code it'll format it properly as code :-)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else that's having this problem, I was having the same problem and found a solution. My localhost was apparently following a path to a cached CSS stylesheet file, even though it had been overwritten countless times.

Solution: Rather than opening the stylesheet directly from the folder to edit, I had to manually open it from my text editor dropdown menu. After hours of frustration, it was that simple. I use Sublime Text, if it makes any difference, but it seems to be a problem with the localhost, and I suspect clearing the cache would have had the same result.