# Why is styles.css showing canceled in Developer Tools?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-development-server

I'm trying to send my 'index.html' file as a response to my local server and within that index.html, there is a link to an external CSS file.

```
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.get("/", function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname+"/index.html");
});
```

and I've included the link in HTML head element like below:

```
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" >
```

Now the problem is that the 'styles.css' file is not loading up on the page. And on the Network section of the Chrome developer tools, it is showing status: canceled in front of the 'styles.css'.

[Here is the screenshot of the canceled status showing for styles.css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQrOd.png)

Why is this happening and what is the solution to it? I've tried other people's solution of deleting the cache, but it doesn't work.

**EDIT**: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36464846/cant-load-external-css-when-in-localhost), I have the exact same problem , and I've tried their solutions too, but it won't work

**EDIT2**: As I tried @wilkoklak's solution , [It's still the same error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wx56Q.png)

[I just added the whole thing from the Bootstrap examples so don't really think that would be a problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGStX.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem of css not being loaded can be solved by using **express.static** and a dedicated static folder (Example: www) for static files.

**Here is the working example using express.static:**

**Step 1:**  Put static files (index.html, styles.css in a static folder named www)

Folder structure:

```
/nodejs-web-demo
   --> server.js

   /www
       --> index.html
       --> styles.css
```

**Step 2:** Create the index.html and styls.css files in www (static) folder

**File name: www/index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles.css">
    <title>Expressjs website</title>
  </head>
  <body>
        <p class="my-style">Hello! How are you doing?</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

**File name: www/styles.css**

```
.my-style{
    color: blue;
}
```

**Step 3:**  Use **express.static** to serve files from static folder

```
const http = require('http')
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const app = express()

app.use(express.static("www"))

app.use('/', function(req,res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/www/index.html'))
})


const server = http.createServer(app)
const port = 3000
server.listen(port)
console.log('Web server started on port # ' + port)
```

**Output:**

```
> node server.js
Web server started on port # 3000
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to serve the css file as well!

You can do this by using `express.static`

Create a folder named `css` and move your `styles.css` there

Your project structure would look similiar to this

```
project/
    css/
        styles.css
    server.js
    index.js
```

Then add this middleware:

```
app.use(express.static('css'))
```

This middleware will look for any match with files inside `css` folder, and send them in response.

When you `GET /` (when you open your webpage), the browser also sends `GET /styles.css` to your server. There was no route handler for `/styles.css` in your app. `express.static` does that for you

Comment: I did that and it doesn't seem to be working either : [

Comment: If this was the problem, wouldn't it 404 instead of being cancelled?

Comment: @YashSingh try `<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />`. The path is "styles.css" since `css` folder is mapped to the root of the page (`/`). Also notice the / before `>`. It's a proper way to close `<link>` tag

Comment: @Quentin Exactly, it's getting canceled, and to be clear, I'm following an online course, and I've checked my steps correctly, So It's really annoying me...

Comment: @wilkoklak Wow it did the magic. Although I don't understand why? The root of the page is the project directory or something right? so why skip a subdirectory like that?
Is it because of using express.static?

Comment: @YashSingh, no, you don't understand. Your project structure is irrelevant. In express you have to specify routes which you want to handle. Express.static is a middleware. Since we didn't provide any path, it will match every request. This middleware looks at request path, and tries to match it with a file in given directory - in our case - in css directory. GET /styles.css matches with css/styles.css. You can read more about it [here](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)

Comment: @wilkoklak Understood, Thanks.